# how should i use single model for multiple controller in rails apllication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<center><h1> welcome </h1></center>
<%= form_for :authors , url: auth_path do |f| %>[this is the controller auth and model author]
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :topic %> 
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :text %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :content ,:cols => "30", :rows => "10" %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

the error is

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Auth#new
```

#### [controller code check it is right or not]

i have tried for it but nothing works
can any one correct the code

class AuthController < ApplicationController
    def index
     @author = Author.all
    end

```
def show

 @author = Author.find(params[:id])

end

 def new

  end

 def create

 @author = Author.find(params[:id])

 @auth = @author.comments.create(comment_params)

 redirect_to @author

end

private

 def author_params

  params.require(:author).permit(:topic, :content)

end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

In controller define method same name as this page name in that get `@author = Author.find(params[:id])` and in view

```
<%= form_for @author, :as => :author, :url => auth_path(@author) do |f| %>
```

And to use single model for multiple controller

```
class User::AuthorsController < ApplicationController
 def welcome
 end
end
```

or

```
module User
 class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
   def welcome
   end
 end
end
```

You can also call your partials this way

```
render :template => "user/authors/welcome"
```

Then in routes.rb

```
namespace :user do
 resources :authors
end
```

Comment: this is nt working i have doubt that about my controller so i send you the code of my controller also

Comment: @TanmayAgrawal - please format it properly.. specify it as code

Comment: if it's a new page then in controller `def new @author = Author.new end` and in view `<%= form_for @author, :as => :author, :url => auth_path(@author) do |f| %>`